# Why can I render all of the Pokémon's names using map, but get a TypeError trying to render one name by itself?

Tags: reactjs, api, use-effect

```
function Shop() {

    const [pokemonData, setPokemonData] = useState([]);
    
   
    useEffect(() => {
        fetchPokemonData();
    }, []);

    const fetchPokemonData = async() => {
        const data = await fetch('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=151');
        const pokemonData = await data.json();
        setPokemonData(pokemonData.results);
        -- pokemonData.results == [{name: 'bulbasaur'}, {name: 'squirtle'}, {name: 'charmander'}];
    };

    return (
        <div>
          
            {pokemonData[0].name}  
            {/* TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined */}

            {pokemonData.map((pokemon) => {
                return (
                    <div>
                        {pokemon.name}
                    </div>
                )
            })} 
            {/* runs with no problems */}

        </div>
    )
}
```

I'm not sure how to ask this question, and I've been stuck on it since yesterday. I hope I've asked my question in a coherent way. Thank you for your help and not destroying me.

Comment: Because until the fetch completes, the array is empty, so element [0] is undefined.

Comment: `{pokemonData.length > 0 && pokemonData[0].name}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
{pokemonData.map((pokemon) => {
       return (
          <div>
              {pokemon.name}
           </div>
         )
})}
```

This code works fine because by default pokemonData state is an empty array and your using map which is an array method but when you do

```
{pokemonData[0].name}
```

you are trying to access `name` property inside the first object which doesn't exists until the request is completed and state is updated and this is causing the issue. You can fix this by doing

```
{pokemonData.length ? pokemonData[0].name : null}
```